# How to combine map and setState

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a recipe book and I trying to get the current recipe page that is opened.

```
{this.state.recipes.map(res => {
  const recipeId = this.state.recipeId;
  if (res.id == recipeId) {
    this.setState({
      selectedRecipe: res
    });
  }
})}
```

As you can see, there is a recipes field in state that holds all the recipes, they are fetched from json earlier.
recipeId is the id of the current page that is openend, it is saved before too and has a value of 0 in this case.
Now what I want to do is extract the recipe with id 0 from all the recipes and save it in selectedRecipe, but for some reasons I get the next error :

"Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

How do I fix this?

Comment: where are you executing the above expression

Comment: This is in the render method.

Comment: You shouldn't call setState in render

Comment: But the problem is that the information is saved in a componentWillMount above, but  the state isn't set yet when I call it somewhere else

Comment: If the information is received in componentWillMount, you should call the above code in componentWillMount itself. P.S. componentWillMount is also deprecated in the latest versions so its better to have all your code in componentWillMount in componentDidMount

Comment: why are you doing a map instead of filter?

Comment: That is what I did now, but I get an error since for some reasons the code is executed faster that the state is saved.
I don't know, I never used filter before

Answer (score 1):

Reorganize your code in this way:

```
const recipeId = this.state.recipeId
const recipe = this.state.recipes.map(res => res.id === recipeId)             

this.setState({ selectedRecipe: recipe })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter method assuming **recipes** is an array declared in the state.

Example :

```
const selectedRecipe = this.state.recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.id === this.state.recipeId);
this.setState({ selectedRecipe });
```

Comment: Used this but it is returning an empty array

Comment: Is your recipeId an integer or a string?

Comment: It's an integer

Answer (score 0):

`map` isn't the thing to use here.

```
const selectedRecipe = this.state.recipes.find(recipe => recipe.id === this.state.recipeId);
this.setState({ selectedRecipe });
```

If you're calling this in render (not `onClick` or anything like that), you're going to enter a loop, where you're forcing a re-render that sets state, causing a re-render that sets state, causing a re-render....

In this case, you'd be better off looking at `componentDidUpdate`. If this is being called in an `onClick`, you should be ok.

Comment: I tried this just after the api setState but it returns an undefined since the state isn't set yet

Comment: Set the initial state in the constructor. `constructor() { this.state = { recipes: [], selectedRecipe: null };`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use `setState` in the render method, you can set the `selectedRecipe` directly after you get the recipes with the help of the array method [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

**Example**

```
componentDidMount() {
  getRecipes().then(recipes => {
    setState(prevState => {
      const { recipeId } = prevState;
      const selectedRecipe = recipes.find(res => res.id === recipeId);

      return { recipes, selectedRecipe };
    });
  });
}
```